# How does a browser execute AJAX response in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

When we:

1. Create a `button_to` with `remote: true`
2. Put javascript code in a `.js.erb` file corresponding to the request

Then the code in the `js.erb` file gets executed on the response.
I was curious as to how that code gets executed in the browser.

Is it through some sort of `eval` call in rails library, or is it related with the `Content-Type` header being set to `text/javascript` in the response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is executed, because the `dataType` of the ajax request is set to `script`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Answer (score 0):

Rails generates javascript code responsible for sending the call, it's the `jquery_ujs.js` file added by default to your layout. Then it simply converts all calls with `data-remote=true` attribute - it prevents default form submits and makes an ajax call to the specified `href`.